# Deleting log files on galaxy tab s 10.5 sm-t800

Tags: rooting, root-access

I have a rooted samsung galaxy tab s 10.5 running android 5.0.2
I am having a lot of storage problems and deleting apps doesnt work, the storage just gradually decreases.

I read somewhere that the log files are supposed to be in /data/log but there is nothing there, i am using es file explorer with the function root explorer on. i have already checked if my device is rooted correctly but there is nothing wrong with it. Also using other file explorers doesnt work.

Where could my log files be? (Or other deletable files that use a lot of space)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! You could check our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for hints :) Besides: most of the logs (at least the system's) are not files, but rather a ring-buffer in memory (oder entries get flushed out when the buffer is full), see our [logging tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info) for details.

Comment: Please see this new article 2017/02/10 [10 most useless apps and games for Android](http://www.androidauthority.com/most-useless-apps-android-749163). Most prominent, but specifically named in the list: ES File Explorer (along with quote-Booster apps, Anti-Virus apps, and Task Killers-unquote)

Answer (score 0):

If the file explorer cannot find it,  I suggest connecting it to your computer.  If you cannot find the log files there, 
 Take note of folder sizes.  Check back every few days and see which folder has grown in size.

This may lead you to whatever is taking up space.

Hope this helps!